# Using Share to Social functionality in an externally hosted module pulled in via HTTPGet

Tags: marketing-cloud, unit-test, ampscript, socialpost

It started with [what I thought was] a simple question:

> Is it possible to use the Share to Social functionality where the area is defined in a template, but the call to that functionality [button/links] resides in a dynamically populated remote module that is pulled in via HTTPGET?

For some reason, I can only get answers from support like "That should work" and "I believe that is correct" but due to our SLA, they cannot look at my AmpScript or HTML and have only pointed me to documentation that is not relevant to this issue.

So does anyone have a solution on how to get this to work or even CAN it be done?

Here is my documentation on my testing so far with a link to all my assets used that seems to prove that it is not working the way that they say is should.

To reiterate, ANY help on this would soooo ROCK [Do I sound desperate enough?]!

LINK TO ASSETS USED IN TESTING:

http://shnosh.com/Social_Share_Testing.zip

TESTING DOCUMENTATION:

> ### Goal:
>
> To use the Share to Social functionality when the call to the area to be shared resides in an externally hosted HTML module that is pulled in via HTTPGET.
>
> ### Testing:
>
> Both tests were sent using the attached test list.
>   [See Attached File: TEST LIST -- Social Share -- Robbie.csv]
>
> #### First Test – No Externally Hosted Module
>
> The first test was a template that had the area to share socially and the call to that area reside within the template itself.
>
> **Code Sent:**
>   [See Attached File: 01 TEST -- Email 01 - Social Share Link in Template -- Source.html]
>
> **Code Received:**
>   [See Attached File: 02 TEST -- Email 01 - Social Share Link in Template -- Delivered Code.html]
>
> **Result:**
>   Share to Social functionality working as expected.
>   [See Attached Screenshot: Screenshot 01 -- Social Sharing Working.jpg]
>
> #### Second Test - Externally Hosted Module
>
> The second test was a template that had the area defined to share socially in the template itself, while the call to that area resides within an externally hosted HTML module that is pulled in via HTTPGET. The module was created by taking the same area to be shared that was in the above working template, placing it in an external piece of HTML code and replacing that area of the template with a call to that code via HTTPGET.
>
> **Code Sent:**
>   [See Attached File: 03 TEST -- Email 02 - Social Share Link in External Module -- Source.html]
>
> **Code Received:**
>   [See Attached File: 04 TEST -- Email 02 - Social Share Link in External Module -- Delivered Code.html]
>
> **Externally Hosted Module:**
>   [See Attached File: Social_Sharing_Test_Module.html]
>
> **Result:**
>   Share to Social functionality not working and showing an error page.
>   [See Attached Screenshot: Screenshot 02 -- Social Sharing Error.jpg]
>
> ### Discovery:
>
> Although the First Test worked correctly, the Second Test appears to be hanging up at the Sales Force Re-direct level [See the URL area of the attached screenshot “Screenshot 02 -- Social Sharing Error.jpg”] and it is not being forwarded to the share area of Facebook.
>
> ### Conclusion:
>
> The fact that Email 01 functions properly and Email 02 gets hung up, but both code sets are identical aside from the Share to Social Link that the SalesForce system inserts, points to that the issue is with the SalesForce system and not the HTML or AmpScrpit code that is in the template.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the AMPScript in your external content is not getting evaluated.  The [**TreatAsContent()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm) function *should* take care of that.

Replace this in `03 TEST -- Email 02 - Social Share Link in External Module -- Source.html`:

```
%%httpget "https://cimzia.s3.amazonaws.com/Testing/Social_Sharing_Test_Module.html"%%
```

With this:

```
%%=treatascontent(httpget("https://cimzia.s3.amazonaws.com/Testing/Social_Sharing_Test_Module.html"))=%%
```

Comment: First off "Thank You" so much Adam for taking the time and trying to help!

Unfortunately, that did not do the trick [and I had such high hopes].

You can download the code that is sent, and the code that was delivered here:
http://shnosh.com/Email03.zip

It is doing the same thing and I am getting the same error page.

Any other thoughts?